# How to highlight complex images/polygons

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to have a [complex image like this](http://members.quicknet.nl/lm.broers/download/riskmap_en.png) in my application. I want to let users click on the complex polygons (countries with borders in this case) and highlight the polygon they clicked on. I have the images that I need to use for that state.

How can I achieve this in android. [Preferably from Java but please let me know any other options that are feasible].

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Vectorize the borders of your map, then read about the [Point in Polygon Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)
2. Use a paint program and fill each country with a different color. When you want to lookup the country from a pixel just access the pixel for this location and use the color as an index into a lookup table.

I would use solution 1 because it is independent on the resolution and very lean from a memory consumption point of view. The second solution otoh only needs modest programming skills.

Comment: Can you show an example of vectorizing the borders of the map? My images have particular shapes and I need to draw the curves and borders to match those. Thank you.

Comment: Use a vector paint program such as inkscape, put your image into the background and draw the borders as polygons ontop of it. Then parse the file to get the raw data. It's either SVG or some XML stuff, don't know anymore, but it was easy to parse.